# Optimizing my database inserts is causing me a display issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I have an ActivityInput tool that lets users on my intranet input their daily workload (in hours) for a selected month (+year) and project.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

As you can see the numbers displayed under the days are hours worked.

But here's how I do it so far:

I simply `INSERT` the inputed data, even when its value is equal to zero.

```
string sql = @"INSERT UserActivity (CalendarDate, ProjectId, Login, ActivityTypeId, Cost) VALUES (@CalendarDate, @ProjectId, @Login, 0, @Cost);";

foreach (string s in sDays) // The parameterised queries avoid any SQL injection risks and delimit the whole command - use it on other SQL commands
{
       string[] values = s.Split(' ');
       using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(m_strConnectionString))
       using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
       {
              command.Parameters.Add("@CalendarDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime(iYear, iMonth, int.Parse(values[1]));
              command.Parameters.Add("@ProjectID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = iProjectid;
              command.Parameters.Add("@Login", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = sLogin;
              command.Parameters.Add("@Cost", SqlDbType.Money).Value = datas[i++];

              connection.Open();
              command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
 }
```

But I want to optimize the whole process and only `INSERT` when the work amount (Cost) is > 0, and simply not have 0-valued rows in my Database.

But here's the reason I'm here:

**How may go through my list of days and still display 0's when there is no matching value in my Database?**

The way I get the list of workloads is through `getFormattedData` that simply throws in this query:

```
SELECT Cost FROM UserActivity WHERE CalendarDate = DayValue AND ProkectId = iProjectId AND Login = sLogin AND ActivityTypeId = 0
```

It works fine if I have rows for every value (even ones = 0), but if I do what I said previously, it'll only have a list containing values > 0 and finding a way to display 0's for inexisting rows (taking week-end that are not displayed into account) seems impossible.

Thank you for sticking around through that long thread, please ask me if you need any precisions.